Not Acceptable Error Show when I call from Postman
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Home")
public class HomeController {
    
    private final IHomeService homeService;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(IHomeService homeService){
        this.homeService = homeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public @ResponseBody Emp hello() {
        return homeService.getEmp();
    }
}

I want to send a object as JSON object when I am trying to send request from Postman:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-04-30T11:39:23.093+00:00",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "path": "/Home/hello"
}


You need to use POST api to pass request body and create record in DB.
    @PostMapping("/hello")
    public @ResponseBody Emp hello( @RequestBody Emp emp ) {
        return homeService.getEmp();
    }

GET API is for retrieval of existing created record.
For more details on HTTP methods, you can refer below HTTP-Methods.
